Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map') in React
I was trying to have my search bar display some results but it did not and is showing the error
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

// import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import lodu from "../../utils/lodu"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
function Topnav() {
    const [query, setquery] = useState("");
    const [searches, setsearches] = useState(null);
    const getSearches = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await lodu.get(`/search/multi?query=${query}`);
            setsearches(data.results)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error is ", error)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getSearches();
    }, [query])
    return (
        <>
            <div className="w-full h-[12vh] relative flex justify-center items-center">
                <i class="text-zinc-400 text-3xl ri-search-2-line"></i>
                <input onChange={(e) => { setquery(e.target.value) }} value={query} className="w-[50%] text-zinc-200 mx-10 p-3 text-xl outline-none bg-transparent border-none" type="text" placeholder="search anything?" />
                {query.length > 0 && (<i
                    onClick={() => setquery("")}
                    class="text-zinc-400 text-3xl ri-xrp-fill"></i>)}
                <div className="w-[50%] absolute max-h-[50vh] bg-zinc-200 top-[90%] overflow-auto">
                    {searches.map((s, i) => (
                        <Link key={i}
                            className="hover:text-zinc-100 hover:bg-zinc-400 duration-200 font-semibold w-[100%] flex justify-start items-center p-8 bg-zinc-200 border-b-2">
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                            <span>hi</span>
                        </Link>
                    )
                    )}


                </div>
            </div>

        </>)
}

export default Topnav


Does this answer your question? × TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

The searches state is null on the initial render cycle and any subsequent render cycle until it is updated. Provide valid initial state or handle the nullable value when rendering.

update your useState default value to empty array.
const[searches,setsearches]=useState([]);


On page load searches is set to null.  Also on page load you're mapping over searches.
Try changing {searches.map((s,i)=>{  to {searches?.map((s,i)=>{ 

You can simply add a check if search result have some value then only map like this:
{searches && searches.length > 0 && searches.map((s, i) => (
                        <Link key={i}
                            className="hover:text-zinc-100 hover:bg-zinc-400 duration-200 font-semibold w-[100%] flex justify-start items-center p-8 bg-zinc-200 border-b-2">
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                            <span>hi</span>
                        </Link>
                    )
                    )}

and update default value of search as follows:
const [searches, setsearches] = useState([]);

Initially, you have set value of searches state variable to null:
const[searches,setsearches]=useState(null);

and then immediately calling map method on null
{null.map((s,i)=>{ 
     return (<Link key={i} 
    className="hover:text-zinc-100 hover:bg-zinc-400 duration-200 font-semibold w-[100%] flex justify-start items-center p-8 bg-zinc-200 border-b-2">
      <img src="" alt="" />
      <span>hi</span>
      </Link>)
    })}

which is generating error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')". To solve this issue, either set initial value of searches to empty array so that map method becomes valid method call on an array (whether empty or not).
const[searches,setsearches]=useState([]);

or check before calling 'map' method on 'searches' variable whether it has been updated with the data returned by "Async" function "getSearches":
{searches && searches.map((s,i)=>{ 
 return (<Link key={i} 
className="hover:text-zinc-100 hover:bg-zinc-400 duration-200 font-semibold w-[100%] flex justify-start items-center p-8 bg-zinc-200 border-b-2">
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <span>hi</span>
  </Link>)
})}

